# How to turn Website into Android App

Tags: java, android, web, android-webview, mobile-website

I have developed one website and now I want to create an android app for it. App should be in sync with web site automatically. I know there are many online free tools for it. But I want to learn Android programming from basic.

I just don't want to link or view the webpages from Smartphone but I must be able to add some android features. 
You may assume I am newbie in an Andriod developing field.
So I want any, good tutorial or book for this. Any suggestion?

For e.g. suraj.com ---> Suraj (android​ app)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build native app, and communication with your server, follow the step

1. Learn [JAVA](https://www.java.net/) and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife)
2. Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
3. Build your server and create web api `(like http://localhost/index.php?data=123)`
4. In android application, call web api to send or receive data ([GET](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html),[POST](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html))

and you can also following this website

1. [Android User Interface Design: Layout Basics](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)
2. [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/)

Comment: I am JAVA developer so its not an issue for me. I want to learn Android programming. But with these steps do I able to use android features? And I could deploy this app on play store?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use android features, just learning Android SDK

Comment: OkkK.Thank you.Could you suggest some good tutorial?

Comment: I've been edit some website for android sdk tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Typically new Android apps use the `ActionBar` UI pattern. If you're looking for something quick, create an Android app with an `ActionBar` for navigation, and use a `WebView` to display mobile-compatible pages from your website.

Comment: Thnk you. Though I am not looking for something quick. Could you be more specific and how to start about this app thing. Any tutorial?

Comment: [Vogella](http://vogella.com/tutorials/android.html) has a really good set of tutorials to get started. It covers nearly everything to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap, if its a simple website, or you can load website through inapp browser into your app. I would recommend to use phonegap though.

Comment: No. I dont want to use any external tool. I want to create it by myself by going thru all process so that I could learn Android stuff more.